# Redirect to other page in when refresh the page using Javascript

Tags: javascript, redirect, dom-events

I have one issue to redirect the page 
I am using this code for redirect the page it will redirect the page also but after that they will ask the conformation massage.

1. stay on page
2. leave the page

   ```
   <script>
         function confirmExit()
         {
             window.location.href='referesh.php';
             return false;
         }
         window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
   </script>
   ```

I don't want that confirmation box

Please help me it will directly redirect to other page.

Comment: Then just remove the confirmation

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code, it might be useful

```
    <script>
    window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
        e = e || window.event;

        // For IE and Firefox prior to version 4
        if (e) {
            e.returnValue = 'Sure?';
        }

        // For Safari
        return 'Sure?';
    };
    </script>
```